# File Deletion Caused VirtualBox NS_ERROR_FAILURE (0x80004005)

Tags: virtualbox, backup, data-recovery, time-machine, file-recovery

I deleted a large file (1 - 8GB for 4 machines) related to VirtualBox because I ran short on memory, MacOs listed this file as one of my biggest on the file system and I thought this might not get used anymore because the necessary data is in the machine related folder. But now all of my virtual machines won't run. When I try to start them, I get an error message that says:

```
Error code: NS_ERROR_FAILURE (0x80004005)
Component: MachineWrap
Interface: IMachine {85632c68-b5bb-4316-a900-5eb28d3413df}
```

I still have all the VDI, VBOX and other machine related files, but I'm not sure where the deleted file was located. I can probably recover the file with Time Machine if I know its path. But Finder won't let me search through all the backup folders after to sort after size.

Can anyone please help me troubleshoot this issue?

The operation

`find . -type f -printf "%s\t%p\n" | sort -n | tail -10`

does not work on my backup drive (even as su):

`ls: .: Operation not permitted`

Comment: given you say `because the necessary data is in the machine related folder` then you know (for sure?) that the files were NOT in the machine related folder? If you know that, then how can you not know where the files were? I'd temporarily create a new VB guest, and see where it creates a "large file"